# Datatables YADCF - input focus on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, yadcf

I'm using the excellent Datatables with Vedmack's YADCF plugin, which is working great.  The only thing I can't figure out is ...

How do I switch focus to a specific YADCF filter text input box on page load?  I've tried the following in and outside of document.ready, but neither work:

```
$('#yadcf-filter--Table-7').ready(function() {
    $('#yadcf-filter--Table-7').focus();
});

... and ...

$('#yadcf-filter--Table-7').load(function() {
    $('#yadcf-filter--Table-7').focus();
});
```

The input box doesn't appear for about 2 seconds after page load and the ID is appended by the plugin, which I assume is why I'm struggling to get it to work.

Any ideas, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - ignore this, the following works fine, I'd just made a daft mistake earlier on:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    yadcf.init(Table, [
        etc, etc...
    ];
    $('#yadcf-filter--Table-7').ready(function() {
        $('#yadcf-filter--Table-7').focus();
    });
});
```